# Is there a way to save a file that is written by a python script, if the python script is killed before it is completed?

Tags: python-3.x, save, export-to-csv

I have been running a web scraper script written in Python. I had to terminate the Python script because of an issue with my internet connection. At the time, the script has run for almost 2-3 hours. I used a for loop to write the data into a CSV file. I had used 'file.close()' to save the file once the for loop is over; but as I terminated the program early, my time of two hours have wasted.

Once I tried to delete the newly created CSV file(its size is 0kB), it is said 'The action can't be completed because the file is open in Python'. I thought that all the data I extracted is now on the RAM.(maybe that's why I don't get the permission to close the 0kB sized CSV file?)

So, is there any way to access those data and write the data into the above-mentioned CSV file? (Otherwise, I will have to run to the same program for another two hours and wait for the results)

Here's my code!

```
#! python3.8
fileCsv = open('newCsv.csv','w',newline='')
outputWriter = csv.writer(fileCsv)


for i in range(100,000): # whatever range
  num, name = 10000, 'hello' # The data extracted from the website
  ourputWriter.writerow([num,name])
  time.sleep(1)

fileCsv.close() # My program was terminated before this line, in the for loop
```

Comment: Don't spam with tags! There's nothing in your code that relates to either selenium nor web-scraping. Read [ask].

Comment: Please let me know if my solution worked for you

Comment: Thank you! I have not yet shut down my computer, can I still save the extracted data on the RAM to the above-mentioned CSV file, without running the code again ( the code that you put here) @Prophet

Comment: The code I pasted should write (append) the data to the file on a disk for every `write` portion. Bit I did not try that actually with killing the process during it run so it's interesting if / how exactly it will actually work. So please let me know what were the actual results on your side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `with` should help here.

```py
with open('newCsv.csv','w') as wr:
    for i in range(100,000): # whatever range
      num, name = 10000, 'hello' # The data extracted from the website
      wr.writerow([num,name])
      time.sleep(1)
```